# JavaFX bulk edit images

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to edit five images I have in a folder at once (using javafx motion blur), rather than select them one after the other. This is my code, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong but when I run it, only the last image in the folder gets edited. The others remain as they are.

```
public class IterateThrough extends Application {

    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    File dir = new File("filepath");
    File [] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();


    if (directoryListing != null) {

        for (File file : directoryListing) {
            if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")){

                //desktop.open(file);

                Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file));


                 //Setting the image view 
                 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 

                 //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
                 imageView.setFitHeight(600); 
                 imageView.setFitWidth(500); 

                 //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view 
                 imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);  

                 // instantiate Motion Blur class
                 MotionBlur motionBlur = new MotionBlur();

                 // set blur radius and blur angle
                 motionBlur.setRadius(15.0);
                 motionBlur.setAngle(110.0);

                 //set imageView effect
                 imageView.setEffect(motionBlur);

                 //Creating a Group object  
                 Group root = new Group(imageView);  

                 //Creating a scene object 
                 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);  

                 //Setting title to the Stage 
                 primaryStage.setTitle("Loading an image");  

                 //Adding scene to the stage 
                 primaryStage.setScene(scene);

                 //Displaying the contents of the stage 
                 primaryStage.show(); 
            } 
        }
     }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); 
}

}
```

Comment: I assume you are using the word “edit” to mean “display,” but I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do.  Do you want to display all of the images are the same time, on top of each other?  Are you trying to display them one a time, while using the blur as a transition effect?

Comment: @VGR I'm trying to display them one at a time while using the blur as a transition effect.

Comment: You’ll probably want to use a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), then.  But first, you’ll need to better define what you want your transition to look like.  Merely blurring an image does not constitute a transition effect.  Did you want one image to increasingly blur, then get replaced by a blurred version of the next image that gradually unblurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you shouldn't just let the primaryStage show() in the for-each loop, because when the primaryStage first show(), the fx thread pause on that instruction, the remaining pictures will not be read and when you close the window, the loop won't continue to go on for remaining, it represents the end of the application.

so it's better to let the primaryStage show() outside the each-loop after all image has been read.

second, you shouldn't use the "Group" container to contains all images, better use VBox/HBox/FlowPane, make sure above image won't covers below's.

here's modified code for reference.

```
public class IterateThrough2 extends Application{
  private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
    File dir = new File("filepath");
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

    if(directoryListing != null){
      for(File file : directoryListing){
        if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")){
          Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file));
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
          imageView.setFitHeight(600);
          imageView.setFitWidth(500);
          imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
          MotionBlur motionBlur = new MotionBlur();
          motionBlur.setRadius(15.0);
          motionBlur.setAngle(110.0);
          imageView.setEffect(motionBlur);
          root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        }
      }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Loading an image");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @diamondgirl
you should enlarge your window, see my uploaded image.